# Ubuntu 15: after installing and configuring java, echo $JAVA_Home is working, Java -version is not working

Tags: command-line, java, environment-variables

I have installed the oracle Java 8 and configure it.

```
cmd-> echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8
cmd-> echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
my oraclejdk.sh file:

cmd->java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

my oraclejdk.sh
It's got empty accidentally now. I logged out couple of times, but still getting above results. I had export commands in it which I don't remember now.

Can you please help me in getting Java running on Ubuntu.

**Note Duplicate:** My question is not related to that mentioned answers. I have a configuration issue, where half echo $JAVA_HOME is showing that Java is installed, but Java -version can't locate the installed Java.

Comment: It's not about installing the Java in general, I need to find out, why my method is not working. It's littler different to that.  and making in duplicate won't solve my problem. I am googling this issue my self, then if you people mark each such issue unanswerable, then it's not helpful.

Comment: What installation / configuration method did you use? All we can see from your question as it stands is that you set a `JAVA_HOME` variable - there's usually more to it than that (e.g. configuring the `update-alternatives` mechanism or manually adding / symlinking the binary path)

Comment: @steeldriver yes, that kind a answer I was looking at where my configuration is lacking.  thanks. is it related to Java or to other software as well which are used for the development ?

Comment: I got my answer from WikiHow at the following URL http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Comment: Yes, see step 9, where they have you set your `PATH`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to your `PATH`

You can verify this easily:

```
$ PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
$ java -version
```

After you've verified it works, edit your `~/.bashrc` file to include the line

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```